# how to add id to a html tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have more than one links with the class of `video` and I want to add an id attribute, When the user clicks on a link.

My code is :

```
   $(function () {$(".video").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).attr('id', 'selected');
   });});
```

After clicking the link, if i see the code. Firebug shows the same code without any change.

Comment: Are you viewing the DOM source?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your code, the issue must be something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try plain JavaScript:

```
this.id = "selected";
```

If that works, then it's a jQuery-fart. If it still doesn't work, make sure you're using Firebug correctly (I don't use it, but I know in IE I have to click a button to refresh the DOM view) and if that still doesn't seem to fix it use a class instead (or a `data-*` attribute)

Comment: It should work, `id` is just another attribute. Perhaps the OP is doing some mistake in the `HTML` itself...

Comment: One thing I have to know how remove the previously added id. When user clicks on another link. And how to add this id to user clicked link.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted so you are doing something wrong elsewhere. Here are a few general points of advice:

- Format your code better to understand what is going on
- Always wrap in an enclosed function that defines $ as jQuery incase
  it is undefined or defined as something else in the global scope
- Apply things like "selected" as classes, not ids
- Don't use the short hand of document ready it is not descriptive of what it is doing and not readable

e.g.

```
(function($) {

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.video').click(function(ev) {

      ev.preventDefault();

      //$(this).attr('id', 'selected');
      $(this).toggleClass('selected'); // This will turn the "selected" class on and off for each click

    });

  );

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you tell me to know how remove the previously added id. When user clicks on another link. And how to add this id to user clicked link.